# How to Synchronize Flask SSE Stream Updates with POST Requests and Server-Side Events?

Tags: python, flask

So i have an SSE stream in my flask application to trigger data changes which looks like following:

```
@bp.route('/stream')
def stream():
    '''
    via this function we can sent updates to the web page which are handled 
    in javascript. This is very important for the live version when new 
    '''
    def generate():
        while True:
            
            if ('data_changed' in session) and ('current_page_content' in session) and session['data_changed']:
                # Assume current_page_content can be generated or retrieved per request
                data = session['current_page_content']
                session['data_changed'] = False
                session.modified = True  # Ensure session is saved
                yield f"data: {data}\n\n"
            time.sleep(0.2)
            
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

Now I have a POST request

```
@bp.route('/filter_window_form', methods=['POST'])
def filter_data():
# modify data
session['data_changed'] = True
session.modified = True  # Ensure session is saved
```

However the change is never set in the session and the SSE stream always has session['data_changed'] as False.

I did check, the sid of session is the same in both.
Why is my session not changed ?

In general i think sessions is not the best way to handle this. Before I had global variable, but that was not good either because it is shared between different browsers and tabs.

How would you solve this?
I have one SSE stream and want to trigger changes from different POST methods, but also other events coming from server side, like SQL-Alchemy Events.